# Fresco. Disk Cache

Tags: android

Привет. В качестве image loader выбрал Fresco. Нужно кешировать картинки на диск и соответсвенно, когда я оффлайн доставать их из кеша. Подскажите как это реализовать.

Ссылки на доку не присылайте пожалуйста. Доку читал, не понял. Поэтому и задаю вопрос здесь. И не предлагайте других вариантов типа Glide и Picasso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем нашел как это можно настроить во Fresco

```
val diskCacheConfig = DiskCacheConfig.newBuilder(this).setBaseDirectoryPath(this.cacheDir)
                .setBaseDirectoryName("image")
                .setMaxCacheSize((100 * ByteConstants.MB).toLong())
                .setMaxCacheSizeOnLowDiskSpace((10 * ByteConstants.MB).toLong())
                .setMaxCacheSizeOnVeryLowDiskSpace((5 * ByteConstants.MB).toLong())
                .setVersion(1)
                .build()

val imagePipelineConfig = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(this)
                .setMainDiskCacheConfig(diskCacheConfig)
                .build()

Fresco.initialize(this, imagePipelineConfig)
```

Достаточно прописать все это в `Application` и использовать для `SimpleDraweeView`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) кеширование в нём происходит автоматически.

[Статья о кешировании](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-influencing-image-caching)

**Круглая трансформация:**

```
/**
 * @author zTrap
 * @date 05.09.2016.
 */
public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }    

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

**Использование:**

```
Picasso.with(this).load(profile.photo)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.no_avatar)
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .resize(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(avatar);
```

Comment: Я fresco не просто так выбрал. Оно умеет кешировать на диск и после вызода из приложения или после перезагрузки устройства все картинки не удаляются

Comment: А кто вам сказал что в *Picasso* это не так?

Comment: Тогда ссылку приложите. И мне все равно нужно только fresco

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне все же нужно с Fresco. Picasso умеет делать круглые изображения автоматически?

Comment: @pavel163 обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Буду это иметь ввиду, но за ответ извините не мошу принять